# how to develop the Mapview in iOS6

Tags: mkmapview, xcode4.5

Can you please tell me what are the changes have to be done to develop the map view in iOS6 in developer perspective.That means any classes or methods or any user interface changes or any thing else.Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe google might have the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that nothing needs to be done differently than before. No new classes or methods (or at least that I've had to use) are available (but you can double check the API differences available from Apple dev site).

The long answer, is that if you are Rotating your mapview, then there probably are changes you would have to make if you previously had working code and dutifully put the Google logo in the lower left corner. So that has to be removed at minimum.

Also if you are rotating your map and counter rotating any annotations (so they remain horizontal), then there is a bug with that where the annotations will get unrotated if the user pans or zooms the map. Bugs have been filed with Apple on this.